# Question about the restricted scope of Google Drive

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

The table in this doc (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth) says "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly" scope is restricted.

But OAuth API verification FAQs (https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#zippy=) only says only Gmail APIs have restricted scope.

I wonder if any of these 2 docs are incorrect. I would like to know if auth/drive.readonly is restricted. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

#### `auth/drive.readonly` is sensitive

It seems that the FAQ link you posted is incomplete. You could "Send Feedback" to let Google know about it, clicking the "burger" button in the top left, and then at the bottom of the sidebar, clicking "Send Feedback".

If you want an easy way to look up which ones are which, when you configure your OAuth2 consent screen in the GCP developers console, you will be asked to configure which scopes you want. It will then classify the chosen scopes according to "sensitive" "restricted" etc.

[image]

Comment: When we select `drive.readonly` we now see that it is a `restricted` scope.

Answer (score 2):

It is currently a sensitive scope, but it was announced in 2019 that it would become a restricted scope (with the exception of drive.file).

> In October of last year, we announced Project Strobe—a Google-wide effort to review third-party developer access to Google account and Android device data. As a result, we rolled out an updated user data policy further restricting access to Gmail data. Today we’re announcing plans to extend the same policy to Google Drive as part of Project Strobe.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/enhancing-security-controls-for-google-drive-third-party-apps

I understand Google has delayed the changes (potentially due to covid), and as a result the documentation it a little confusing right now.

Answer (score 0):

The GCP console is the source of truth. I find that auth/drive.readonly is with sensitive scope right now.